# Inverse of a matrix in JuMP constraints

Tags: julia, nonlinear-optimization, julia-jump

I have tried to follow the approach mentioned here: [JuMP constraints involving matrix inverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62622919/jump-constraints-involving-matrix-inverse). But I am still not able to get my code to run.

My code is as follows:

```
using JuMP, Ipopt, LinearAlgebra
FP = Model(solver=IpoptSolver())
@variable(FP, x[1:2,1:2] >= 0)
@objective(FP, Max, 0)

@NLconstraint(FP, inv(x) <= 0.5*I)

status = solve(FP)
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: LoadError: Unexpected object x[i,j] >= 0 for all i in {1,2}, j in {1,2} in nonlinear expression.
```

I am not sure what is going wrong. I am using JuMP 0.18.6. Could you please help? Thanks.

Comment: This works after upgrading JuMP to the latest version and following the approach mentioned here: https://github.com/jump-dev/JuMP.jl/issues/2060